# How to backfill data

Tags: stata

I have data that looks something like:

```
n   year    y
1   2000    
1   2000        
1   2001    
1   2002    6
1   2002    6
1   2003    9
2   2000    
2   2000    
2   2001        
2   2002    1
2   2002    9
2   2003    4
3   2000    
3   2001    
3   2002    3
3   2002    3
3   2003    5
3   2003    5
4   1999    
4   2000    
4   2001    
4   2002    
4   2002    4
```

How can I fill in the `y` value for all `year`s before `2002` with the  `y` value corresponding to the ~first~ observation of `2002` - and do this by `n`?

For example, for `n==2`, the first `y` value of `year==2002` is `1`. Thus, I would want to fill in the three `y` values of years `2000` (2) and `2001` (1) with `1`. The new dataset would be:

```
n   year    y
1   2000    6
1   2000    6   
1   2001    6
1   2002    6
1   2002    6
1   2003    9
2   2000    1
2   2000    1
2   2001    1   
2   2002    1
2   2002    9
2   2003    4
3   2000    3
3   2001    3
3   2002    3
3   2002    3
3   2003    5
3   2003    5
4   1999    
4   2000    
4   2001    
4   2002    
4   2002    4
```

Note that the years before `2002` for `n==4` did not get filled in because the first observation where `year==2002` is blank.

I think that a solution may be along the lines of:

```
bysort n: gen temp = y[1] if year==2002
replace y = temp if year<2002
drop temp
```

But I am not sure about the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (perhaps inelegant) solution:

```
sort n year, stable // [1]
gen y2 = y
by n year: gen _y = y2[1] if year == 2002 // [2]
egen _y2 = max(_y), by(n) // [3]
replace y2 = _y2 if year < 2002 // [4]
drop _*

li, sepby(n) noobs
```

yielding:

```
  +-------------------+
  | n   year   y   y2 |
  |-------------------|
  | 1   2000   .    6 |
  | 1   2000   .    6 |
  | 1   2001   .    6 |
  | 1   2002   6    6 |
  | 1   2002   6    6 |
  | 1   2003   9    9 |
  |-------------------|
  | 2   2000   .    1 |
  | 2   2000   .    1 |
  | 2   2001   .    1 |
  | 2   2002   1    1 |
  | 2   2002   9    9 |
  | 2   2003   4    4 |
  |-------------------|
  | 3   2000   .    3 |
  | 3   2001   .    3 |
  | 3   2002   3    3 |
  | 3   2002   3    3 |
  | 3   2003   5    5 |
  | 3   2003   5    5 |
  |-------------------|
  | 4   1999   .    . |
  | 4   2000   .    . |
  | 4   2001   .    . |
  | 4   2002   .    . |
  | 4   2002   4    4 |
  +-------------------+
```

Notes:
[1] The `stable` option preserves the ordering of `y`.
[2] Generates `_y` equal to the first observation where `year == 2002` only. Note that you need `by n year` or else `y[1]` is the first observation of the `n` group even when `year != 2002` (but present only for observations where `year == 2002`).
[3] Fills in `_y` across the `n` group.
[4] Replaces `y2` for years earlier than 2002.

Answer (score 1):

`mipolate` from SSC offers "backward" interpolation, as follows:

```
. ssc inst mipolate 

. bysort n: mipolate y year, gen(y2) backward

. l

     +-------------------+
     | n   year   y   y2 |
     |-------------------|
  1. | 1   2000   .    6 |
  2. | 1   2000   .    6 |
  3. | 1   2001   .    6 |
  4. | 1   2002   6    6 |
  5. | 1   2002   6    6 |
     |-------------------|
  6. | 1   2003   9    9 |
  7. | 2   2000   .    5 |
  8. | 2   2000   .    5 |
  9. | 2   2001   .    5 |
 10. | 2   2002   1    5 |
     |-------------------|
 11. | 2   2002   9    5 |
 12. | 2   2003   4    4 |
 13. | 3   2000   .    3 |
 14. | 3   2001   .    3 |
 15. | 3   2002   3    3 |
     |-------------------|
 16. | 3   2002   3    3 |
 17. | 3   2003   5    5 |
 18. | 3   2003   5    5 |
 19. | 4   1999   .    4 |
 20. | 4   2000   .    4 |
     |-------------------|
 21. | 4   2001   .    4 |
 22. | 4   2002   .    4 |
 23. | 4   2002   4    4 |
     +-------------------+
```

I mention this because it may be of interest to others interested in the question. A key here is that multiple observations for the same identifier and year are averaged first, which is not what you want.

Your particular version of the question is **highly fragile** because somehow you know that the first value of several is the one to use, but nothing in the data you show us flags which or why. Sort the data on `n year` and which of various duplicates comes first may well change! This is a dangerous situation for data management.